# inserting array to DB in laravel form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to insert array to DB ( double rows with the same FK (product_id) ) , which i have parent table(Products) and child table(Product_translation) .
I have 2 Model with relationship and getting the lastinserted Id of the product table , but the issue with me now is it's save word(array) to DB , instead of loop on this array to insert it correclty using laravel form : and here's my form

```
 {!!Form::text('title[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" )!!} 

 {!!Form::text('language[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ])!!} 

  {!!Form::text('title[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" )!!} 

  {!!Form::text('language[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" )!!}
```

and the controller function here's :

```
  function store( ){
            $parentproduct = new Product();
            $parentproduct->id = Input::get('id');
            $parentproduct->save();
            $insertedId = $parentproduct->id;
            $langArray = Input::get('language');
            $titleArray = Input::get('title');
             $count = count($titleArray);
            for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)

        { 

        $product = new ProductsTranslation(array('language' => $langArray[$i], 'title' => $titleArray[$i],
        $product->product_id = $insertedId));
        $product->save();
        }
            DB::table('products_translations')->insert($product);
        }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Creating default object from empty value

Which is referring to that line :

### $product->product_id = $insertedId

Updated now i have a problem to  store the array to my database :

My form getting me this array :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => null
    "product_id" => 225
    "title" => "English Title"
    "language" => "En"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => null
    "product_id" => 225
    "title" => "Arabic title"
    "language" => "Ar"
  ]
]
```

And i need to save this to database but it didn't !

which i'm using this code at the controller :

```
function store(Request $request) {
    $parentproduct = new Product();
    $parentproduct->id = Input::get('id');
    $parentproduct->save();
    $insertedId = $parentproduct->id;

     foreach ($request->input('language') as $i=>$language) {

         $insertprod[] = array(
        'id' =>$request->input('id')[$i], 
       'product_id'=>$parentproduct->id,
        'title' =>$request->input('title')[$i],
        'language' => $request->input('language')[$i],    
         );
    DB::table('products_translations')->insert($insertprod); 

     }
     ProductsTranslation::insert($insertprod); 
     DB::table('products_translations')->insert($insertprod);
    // DB::table('products_translations')->update(['change' => Input::all()]);
      DB::table('products_translations')->insert($insertprod);
     //ProductsTranslation::create($insertprod);
      dd($insertprod); 

}
```

When i remove the comment from the line of create

ProductsTranslation::create($insertprod);

It's getting me an error that can't update or insert FK Product_id !

How can save that array to my db ?

Comment: You're opening with `[` but closing with `)` ??

Comment: Also, `$product->product_id = $insertedId` is going to throw an error as `$product` won't be defined yet (unless the error is you've put a closing `)` in the wrong place

Comment: Sorry , it didn't understand what do you mean? do you mean the form ?
Here's its:
<form action="/adminPanel/products/store" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="demo-form2">
 
     {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: Oh , you are right , I close it wrong but i still have the same error when i make it :
 $product = new ProductsTranslation(array('language' => $langArray[$i], 'title' => $titleArray[$i],
             $product->product_id = $insertedId));

Comment: So how can i defind the value $product->product_id = $insertedId

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to this one ( This Insert All Array in your table) with ther use of DB class ..

```
function store( ){
        $parentproduct = new Product();
        $parentproduct->id = Input::get('id');
        $parentproduct->save();
        $product = array();
        $insertedId = $parentproduct->id;
        $langArray = Input::get('language');
        $titleArray = Input::get('title');
         $count = count($titleArray);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ 
           $product[]  = array(
                    'language'=>$langArray[$i],
                    'title' =>$titleArray[$i],
                    'product_id'=> $insertedId );

         }
        DB::table('products_translations')->insert($products);
    }
```

If you want to user modal of producttranslations than replace this ..

```
function store( ){
        $parentproduct = new Product();
        $parentproduct->id = Input::get('id');
        $parentproduct->save();
        $insertedId = $parentproduct->id;
        $langArray = Input::get('language');
        $titleArray = Input::get('title');
         $count = count($titleArray);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ 

           $product = ProductsTranslation::firstOrCreate(array('language' =>   $langArray[$i], 'title' => $titleArray[$i], 'product_id'=>$insertedId));
           or 
           $product = new ProductsTranslation();


           $product->language =$langArray[$i];
           $product->title =$titleArray[$i];
           $product->product_id =$insertedId;
           $product->save();

         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , it didn't show me  errors , but it didn't save the values too

Comment: Please try with $product = new ProductsTranslation(); this line

Comment: function store( ){
        $parentproduct = new Product();
        $parentproduct->id = Input::get('id');
        $parentproduct->save();
        $insertedId = $parentproduct->id;
        $langArray = Input::get('language');
        $titleArray = Input::get('title');
         
         $count = count($titleArray);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ 
           $product = new ProductsTranslation();
           $product->language =$langArray[$i];
           $product->title =$titleArray[$i];
           $product->product_id =$insertedId;
           $product->save();
I did that

Comment: Hello please inster this linn... 
$product = new ProductsTranslation;

without bracket

Comment: I added it before the for loop , but nothing happened too , the data not saved

Comment: Not before but you have to add in between loop

Comment: between them without {} ? but how can i do that?

Comment: I have removed {} for the for loop , but then  i have this error : 
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 2', 'D:\Webs_Work\PremuimeProject\app\Http\Controllers\ProductsController.php', '158', array('parentproduct' => object(Product), 'insertedId' => '169', 'langArray' => array('jhgqkk', 'h'), 'titleArray' => array('kjl', 'jh'), 'count' => '2', 'i' => '2', 'product' => object(ProductsTranslation))) in ProductsController.php line 158

Comment: Undefined offset: 2

Comment: Don't remove {} this you need to change this line
$product = new ProductsTranslation;

Comment: here it's 
`function store( ){
        $parentproduct = new Product();
        $parentproduct->id = Input::get('id');
        $parentproduct->save();
        $insertedId = $parentproduct->id;
        $langArray = Input::get('language');
        $titleArray = Input::get('title');
          $product = new ProductsTranslation();
         $count = count($titleArray);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ 
           $product->language =$langArray[$i];
           $product->title =$titleArray[$i];
           $product->product_id =$insertedId;
           $product->save();
         }`

Comment: I think it's not right using for : which that's result when i write dd($product)
#attributes: array:6 [▼
    "language" => "en"
    "title" => " sdf`f"
    "product_id" => 177
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-24 12:01:34"
    "created_at" => "2017-03-24 12:01:34"
    "id" => 68
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▼
    "language" => "en"
    "title" => " sdf`f"
    "product_id" => 177
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-24 12:01:34"
    "created_at" => "2017-03-24 12:01:34"
    "id" => 68
  ]

Comment: Can you chec this code
`function store(Request $request) {
        $parentproduct = new Product();
        $parentproduct->id = Input::get('id');
        $parentproduct->save();
        $insertedId = $parentproduct->id;
         foreach ($request->input('language') as $i=>$language) {
          $insertprod[] = array(
        'id' =>$request->input('id')[$i], 
        'title' =>$request->input('title')[$i],
        'language' => $request->input('language')[$i],
         $insertedId=>$request->input('product_id')
    );         }  ProductsTranslation::insert($insertprod); 
`

Comment: It getting me this error : 
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Comment: You Can not write $request->input('id')[$i]  it is wrong syntex

Comment: I have jst misteck Please check 
please update this line 
DB::table('products_translations')->insert($products);
to 
DB::table('products_translations')->insert($product);